# Rails as_json throwing "can't convert Symbol into Integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to dynamically change what associations and methods are returned from the as_json function of my model in a rails controller action based on parameters passed to the action.

Here are the parameters being passed to the action:

```
{"include"=>{"service_requests"=>"status"},
"methods"=>["service_request_count"],
"program_id"=>""}
```

Here is what my controller action is doing:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @projects.as_json(:include => params[:include]), :methods => params[:methods] }
end
```

This is giving the error: "can't convert Symbol into Integer". Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Whereas the argument you're giving to as_json is

```
:include => { :service_requests => :status }
```

it needs to be

```
:include => { :service_requests => { :include => :status } }
```

Comment: :status is an association but your point is still valid. So you're saying that it should be :service_requests => { :include => :status } ?